# `error` を投げることがある巨大な再帰ケースをできるだけ簡単に `Maybe` 化する方法はありますか

Tags: haskell

Haskell で、ある再帰直和型 `T` に対し、 `T -> T` のような関数があり、既に実装されているとします。たとえば、

```
data T = Z
       | One T
       | Two T T
       | Three T T T
       | ..  -- 沢山あります

f :: T -> T
f Z             = Z
f (One t)       = One (f t)
f (Two t1 t2)   = Two (f t2) (f t1)  -- 単純なトラバーサルではない
f (Three Z Z Z) = error "Three 0s are illegal"
f .. -- ずっと続きます
```

一部のケースは、ありえない入力だということで、 `error` を使って例外を飛ばしています。

この関数を `T -> Maybe T` や `T -> Either String T` のように型を変えて「行儀を良くして」例外を投げないようにしたいのですが、どのようにするのが一番良いのか、が質問です。

```
f :: T -> Either String T
f Z             = return Z
f (One t)       = liftM One (f t)
f (Two t1 t2)   = liftM2 Two (f t2) (f t1)
f (Three Z Z Z) = fail "Three 0s are illegal"
f ..
```

などのようにモナドなり、アプリカティブファンクターなり、使用すると書けるのは判るのですが、コンストラクタ数が多い直和型の場合、追加コードを書いていて鬱々としてきます。

通常の Haskell では IO 関連だと例外は `catch` できるのですが、この場合、元の関数は IO を使いませんから、 IO 汚染させたくありません。非IO でも例外を catch できる言語では間違いなく例外を使う例なので当惑しています。

元のソースコードのをできるだけ変更せずに `Either`化や `Maybe`化したいのですが、 Haskell では無理なのでしょうか。

Comment: コンストラクタ数が多い場合、所定の方法はTemplate Haskellでしょうね。個人的にはTemplate Haskellをあんまり好きじゃないから特におすすめできませんけど。コンストラクタ数を減らせない、TにNothingのようなコンストラクタに添えられない場合は、かなり悪い状況だと思います。（ご質問の答えにならなくてすみません。）

Comment: いえ、それで充分なお答になっていると思います。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Template Haskell(QuasiQuoter)が嫌いでなければ、それを実現するための糖衣があります。

[applicative-quoters](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/applicative-quoters-0.1.0.8/docs/Control-Applicative-QQ-Idiom.html)パッケージで定義されているものを利用すると、

```
f (Two t1 t2) = [i| Two (f t2) (f t1) |]
```

のように、`[i| … |]`で囲むだけで、自動的に `Two <$> f t2 <*> f t1` に変換してくれますが、ネストしている場合に対応していない点に注意が必要です。

もう一つの方法として、純粋な例外ハンドラを利用するという方法もあります。

[spoon](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon/docs/Control-Spoon.html)パッケージで提供されている`teaspoon :: a -> Maybe a`は、例外が発生したとき`Nothing`、発生しなかった場合は`Just`で結果を返します。例外ハンドラをカスタマイズする`teaspoonWithHandles :: Handles a -> a -> Maybe a`という関数も用意されています。

おそらく、後者が求めているのに近いと思います。参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: spoonは内部で`unsafePerformIO`と`Control.Exception.catches`を使っている関係で、非同期例外と相性が悪いので注意して使う必要があります。`catches`が非同期例外を同期例外としてrethowするため、`teaspoon expr`というthunkを評価中に非同期例外を受け取るとthunkは例外で書き換えられ、以後再評価すると例外を上げるようになります。

Comment: 個人的には QuasiQout は大好きなのですが、業務上の制約から使えません。非常にスレッドを多用するシステムですので spoon も使えないと思われます。残念ですが、否定的な結論であっても納得ができたのでとても助かりました！